# change field name of an index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to ask that, how to change field names in elasticsearch index.
I mean,

```
"_source": {
"name_of_field": "lorem"
}
```

**change "name_of_field" to "new_name"**

Comment: the both answer solves the question but the exact match one by escoder. I'm not able to select both so I ve selected escoder's answer. But i ve upvoted yours. Thanks for answering.

Comment: sure no worries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Elasticsearch Ninja you can use the alias, you can also use update by query API

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "name":"John"
}
```

**Update by Query API**

```
POST /_update_by_query

{
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "exists": {
                "field": "title"
            }
        }
    }
  },
  "script" : {
    "inline": "ctx._source.title = ctx._source.name; ctx._source.remove(\"name\");"
  }
}
```

**By the above query `name` field name will be changed to `title`**

Comment: @rknd did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: Thanks for answer. This solves the question

Answer (score 1):

Refer [official ES documentation on how to rename a field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#rename-existing-field), you need to use `alias` for doing it.

**From the same docs**

> Renaming a field would invalidate data already indexed under the old
> field name. Instead, add an alias field to create an alternate field
> name.